# Python Dataframe imports csv row names and values into columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I have a csv file not a column wise format but have the information in row wise format. I want to import that information in proper format. I have many such files but all of them follow same naming format.

My code:

```
#csv_file1
Report Date 2/1/2021
Report Time 1:23:09 PM
    
    MEASUREMENTS
col1    58.6235148
Col2    4.877245992
Col3    51.81711392
Col4    3.712866254
Col5    192.3900136

df = pd.read_csv('csv_file1.csv')
```

Present output:

```
ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 2 fields in line 6, saw 4
```

Expected output:

```
df = 

index                   col1     col2     col3     col4     col5     
2/1/2021 1:23:09 PM    35148     4.87     51.81    3.71     192.39
```

Actual CSV file
[image]

Comment: Pass `skiprows` to `read_csv`

Comment: @QuangHoang How do I read individual rows? `skiprows` skips initial rows but reads rest of the rows together

Comment: can you paste the exact raw output of your file? put it in a github gist if that's easier. I suspect there maybe a `#` to show the comments for the metadata

Comment: @Manakin I added a screenshot of the CSV file.

Comment: open it in a text editor not excel - doesn't look like there are any comments tho.

Answer (score 0):

First import your data without any splitting in a series `raw` and then extract the required data convert and them into a dataframe `df`:

```
import pandas as pd
import io

s = """Report Date 2/1/2021
Report Time 1:23:09 PM
    
    MEASUREMENTS
col1    58.6235148
Col2    4.877245992
Col3    51.81711392
Col4    3.712866254
Col5    192.3900136"""

raw = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(s), header=None, squeeze=True)

date = pd.to_datetime(raw[0].replace('Report Date ','') + raw[1].replace('Report Time',''))
values = raw[3:].str.replace(r'.* ', '', regex=True).astype(float)
df = pd.DataFrame([values.tolist()], index = [date], columns=[f'Col{i+1}' for i in range(len(values))])
```

Result:

```
                          Col1      Col2       Col3      Col4        Col5
2021-02-01 13:23:09  58.623515  4.877246  51.817114  3.712866  192.390014
```

If your data my contain a comma `,` (which is the default delimiter) specify any other character as delimiter that you know for sure that it'll not occur in your data, e.g. `sep='$'`.

Comment: Here, you have the whole data stored inside the variable `s`. In my case, how do I import the file data into that variable `s`?

Comment: this is just a demonstration, you would of course use `pd.read_csv('my_file.csv', sep='\n', header=None)[0]`. Instead of `'\n'` you can use any other character you know that it doen't occur in your files.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously not the best 'pythonic' way of achieving it.. improvements & suggestions are welcome! Opening the document twice will play a serious role on time, but this reproduces the expected result:

```
from csv import reader

path= r'C:\Users\Desktop'

with open(path + '/csv_file1.csv', 'r') as f:
    csv_reader = reader(f)
    x= []
    for i, j in csv_reader:
        x.append(j)
    
df= pd.read_csv(path + '/csv_file1.csv', index_col= 0, skiprows= 3).T
df.index= df.index.str.replace(r'MEASUREMENTS', x[0])
```